# Android: Change who's calling

Tags: java, android

I tried searching around google for a way to replace or append whos calling.
E.g.: someone is calling that you do not have stored in the contacts list, and I wish to do a lookup in an application on the phone for that phonenumber.

Is that possible? I've seen apps doing it, but I failed to see API docs on Android API docs page.

Regards

Comment: Doesn't TrueCaller give any API for this?